# Colorbar for Matplotlib graph with normalized confusion matrix doesn't update values

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, colorbar

I am trying to solve a multi-class machine learning problem with KNearest Neighbors, and am plotting a confusion matrix for the predictions of all my 10 classes in my data using Matplotlib.pyplot's imshow. Some classes have considerably more occurrences in the data than others, up to 3000 where others may only have 50, so I normalized it to just show the percentage. There is a colorbar next to the graph, that if not normalized, will range from 1 to 3000, which makes sense. However after normalizing it, the range stays all the way up to 3000. I am using a plotting function supplied by Scikit Learn themselves at their site [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_confusion_matrix.html). Is there something obvious I'm missing, or is there an extra step to reduce the colorbar value range ?

Code

```
virdis = plt.cm.viridis
blues = plt.cm.Blues
autumn = plt.cm.autumn

def plot_confusion_matrix(cm, classes,
                          normalize=False,
                          title='Confusion matrix',
                          cmap=blues):
    """
    This function prints and plots the confusion matrix.
    Normalization can be applied by setting `normalize=True`.
    """
    plt.imshow(cm, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cmap)
    plt.title(title)

    bounds=[0, .1, .2, .3, .4, .5, .6, .7, .8, .9, 1]
    plt.colorbar(boundaries=bounds)

    tick_marks = np.arange(len(classes))
    plt.xticks(tick_marks, classes, rotation=45)
    plt.yticks(tick_marks, classes)

    if normalize:
        cm = cm.astype('float') / cm.sum(axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]
        print("Normalized confusion matrix")
    else:
        print('Confusion matrix, without normalization')

    cm = np.around(cm, decimals=3)

    thresh = cm.max() / 2.

    for i, j in itertools.product(range(cm.shape[0]), range(cm.shape[1])):
        plt.text(j, i, cm[i, j],
                 horizontalalignment="center",
                 color="white" if i == 9 and j == 9 else "black")

    plt.ylabel('True label')
    plt.xlabel('Predicted label')

knn = KNeighborsClassifier()
knn.fit(X_train, y_train)

knn_score = knn.score(X_test, y_test)
knn_fold_score = model_selection.cross_val_score(knn, X_test, y_test, cv=10).mean()
predictions = knn.predict(X_test)

c_matrix = confusion_matrix(y_test, predictions)

# Plot normalized confusion matrix
plt.figure()
plot_confusion_matrix(c_matrix, classes=country_names, normalize=True,
                      title='Normalized confusion matrix')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can understand, the colorbar and its range stay and should stay with the plot, i.e. `plt.imshow`. The Scikit Learn example and your example both plot the matrix before doing or deciding whether to do normalization. Therefore, the two plots and their associated colorbars look exactly the same. If you processing normalization before plotting, i.e. moving the following block:

```
if normalize:
    cm = cm.astype('float') / cm.sum(axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]
    print("Normalized confusion matrix")
else:
    print('Confusion matrix, without normalization')

cm = np.around(cm, decimals=3)
```

to in front of `plt.imshow(cm, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cmap)`, the colorbar for normalized plot will then ranges from 0 to 1. Again, just to remind you, (the color of) the plot itself will also change. I think it won't be a good idea to just change text labels for the colorbar to be ranging from 0 to 1 without changing the colorbar itself and its associated plot.